# Avoid appending attribute in URL on postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am developing a website to get some user's report. I am using URL rewriter to read the user ID directly from the URL setting Webconfig file as follows:

```
<rewriter>
    <rewrite url="~/Report/(.+)" to="~/_ClientReport.aspx?UserID=$1" processing="stop"/>
</rewriter>
```

This creates a URL from which I read the parameter and display the corresponding User's information.

http://localhost:37078/Report/4277

I have a button that creates a postback but when doing so it appends the UserId parameter again in the URL like this:

http://localhost:37078/Report/4277?UserID=4277

Could you help me to know how can I avoid this?

Comment: Try this `form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;`

Comment: @VDWWD - This worked perfectly! Thanks a lot